# Let $X$ be a random variable with probability density function $f$. Prove that the probability distribution function of $X$ is non-decreasing

Tags: probability-distributions

Can anyone please help me with this random variable question I've stumbled across.

Recall from calculus that a function $h$ is called *non-decreasing* if $x \le y$ implies $h(x) \le h(y)$, for every $x, y \in \mathop{\mathrm{dom}} h$.

Q1a) Let $X$ be a continuous random variable with probability density function $f$. Prove
that the probability distribution function of $X$ is non-decreasing.

I'm assuming this means show $F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f(y)\,dy$, is a non-decreasing function of $x$ in $\mathbb R$.

Q1b) Show that $\lim_{x\to-\infty} F(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty} F(x) = 1$, and explain the probabilistic meaning of these facts.

Sorry about the layout i'm not used to using this site, hope it makes sense!

Comment: Hint for Q1a) $f \ge 0$.

Comment: Hint for Q1b) $F(x) = \lim_{a \to -\infty} \int_{a}^x f(y)\ dy = \lim_{a \to -\infty} (F(x) - F(a))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do 1(b): 
$F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f(t)\ dt$ is an improper integral, which by definition of improper integral means $\lim_{a \to -\infty} \int_a^x f(t)\ dt$.  Now $\int_a^x f(t)\ dt = F(x) - F(a)$, so
$$ F(x) = \lim_{a \to -\infty} (F(x) - F(a)) = F(x) - \lim_{a \to -\infty} F(a)$$
and you can solve for $\lim_{a \to -\infty} F(a)$.

As for $\lim_{x \to \infty} F(x) = \lim_{x \to \infty} \int_{-\infty}^x f(t)\ dt$, that is $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)\ dt$, which according to the  definition of a probability density function must be $1$.

Comment: The proof by Robert on the upper limit does depend on f approaching ∞ as x does.  Then to know that the limit equals 1 relies on the definition of a probability density. That f tends to 0 as x approaches +∞ or −∞ is a required property for a probability desnity function.

Comment: @MichaelChernick: where do you see $f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$ written as a required property for a probability density?  The only real requirements are $f \ge 0$ and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\ dx = 1$.  Some elementary texts (wanting to avoid Lebesgue integration) may require $f$ to be piecewise continuous.  But I haven't seen any that required limits of $0$.

Comment: As I said it is required because it would be impossible for ∫f(x) dx=1 integrating over (-∞, ∞) if f does not go to 0 as x approaches ∞!!!

Comment: No.  For example, try an $f$ whose graph consists of infinitely many triangular "bumps", the $n$'th bump (for positive integers $n$) having height $2n$ and width $2^{-n}/n$, so area $2^{-n}$.

Comment: Or if you prefer an analytic function, try $6 \pi^{-5/2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty n e^{-n^6 (x-n)^2}$.

Comment: Thanks.  I wasn't thinking of densities that get spikey like that.  You have a case where f doesn't convwerge to anything.  It seems that along a sequence of integers F increases to infinity and along another subsequence it goes to 0. So I guess you are right.

Comment: Maybe between mathematicians and statisticians.  Maybe this illustrates a difference between statisticians and mathematicians.  We think of distributions with nice smooth densities all of which go to 0 in the right and left tails while matematicians think of pathological cases to show counterexamples to our ideal.

Answer (score 1):

No need for a pdf $f.$ A cdf $F$
$$F(X)=\operatorname P(X\le x)$$
is *always*

- non-decreasing:
  $$x\le y\implies F(y)=F(x)+\operatorname P(x<X\le y)\ge F(x),$$
- satisfying $\lim_{-\infty}F=0,$ $\lim_{+\infty}F=1:$
  $$\lim_{+\infty}F=\operatorname P(\cup_{n\in\Bbb N}[X\le n])=\operatorname P(\Bbb R)=1,$$
  $$\lim_{-\infty}F=\operatorname P(\cap_{n\in-\Bbb N}[X\le-n])=\operatorname P(\varnothing)=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes because the density function is never less than 0 the integral from -∞ to x cannot be larger than from -∞ to y for any y>x.  So F is monotone non-decreasing.  The density function f has to go to 0 as x approaches + or - ∞.  So lim x→−∞ F(x)=0.  The fact that lim x→∞ F(x)=1 is a requirement for f to be a probability density with F as its CDF. There is no other way to see that f integrates to 1 from the information given.  All you can deduce is that it integrates to a positive constant.

Comment: when you say 'the integral from -∞ to x cannot be larger than from -∞ to y for any y>x' do you mean ∫-∞ to x  of  f(y)dy < ∫-∞ to y  of  f(y)dy ?

Comment: @Micheal, I know this sounds silly but why does the density function f HAVE to go to 0 as x approaches + or - ∞?

Comment: Not at all silly.  Actually $f$ doesn't have to go to $0$ as $x \to + \infty$ or $-\infty$.  Fortunately, that's irrelevant to the questions being asked.

Comment: @Robert Israel, can you please endeavour to spread some light on what to do?

Comment: @user31024 First of all I wouldn't use y as both the upper limit of integration and the variable being integrated.  y is any fixed value greater than x and I am just saying that if a function f is greater than 0 between x and y it must integrate to something positive.  If f does not tend to 0 but stays positive as it approaches either +∞ or −∞ the integral would be infinite.  I don't understand what Robert is saying, If f does not go to 0 as x tends to +∞ it would not be possible for lim x→∞ F(x)=1  instead it would tend to +∞ and at some point exceed 1!

Comment: @MichaelChernick Start with a 'nice' density $f$ that goes to $0$ if $x$ tends to $+\infty$. Then define $g$ by $x\mapsto5$ if $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $x\mapsto f\left(x\right)$
otherwise. This less nice $g$ can - just like $f$ - also serve as
density, and this for the same distribution. However, it does not
go to $0$ if $x$ tends to $+\infty$. Robert is right in this.